# Many nullable objects, how to set property at the end of path

Tags: kotlin

Let's assume we have to set property on object "ObjectD". To get this object we have to go through path of nullable objects:

```
objectA.objectB?.objectC?.objectD?.property = 1234
```

The problem is that, each object have to be checked, if is null then should be created.

Is there any way to do this without if statements?

```
if (objectA.objectB == null) {
    objectA.objectB = ObjectB().apply {
        objectC = ObjectC().apply {
            objectD = ObjectD().apply {property = 1444}
        }
    }
} else {
    if (objectA.objectB.objectC == null) {
        objectA.objectB.objectC = ObjectC().apply {
            objectD = ObjectD().apply {property = 144}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I do not avoid `if` or possibly the ternary operator `(? :)`

But, I generally make sure that all the objects that I will use are non-null before their use.

In your case I would avoid nesting `if`, by writing:

```
val wasBNull = false
val wasCNull = false
if (objectA.objectB == null) {
   wasBNull = true
   objectA.objectB = ObjectB()
}
if (objectA.objectB.objectC == null) {
   wasCNull = true
   objectA.objectB.objectC = ObjectC()
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, I think, you should create method(s) like `getOrCreateObjectB(): ObjectB`.
If you are able to change the internals of these objects - make this method(s) as a class member function, if not - as an extension. Example of extension is below:

```
fun ObjectA.getOrCreateObjectB(): ObjectB {
    if (objectB == null) objectB = ObjectB()
    return objectB
}
```

Eventually, you'll end up with something like this:
`objectA.getOrCreateObjectB().getOrCreateObjectC().getOrCreateObjectD().property = 1234`

Answer (score 0):

Having to modify a deeply nested object directly is a sign of a fundamental design problem (lack of encapsulation). Except maybe if your object graph is a model of some non-smart data structure such as JSON or XML.

At the very least, you should break up all the external object creation. Each object in the tree can have a function for ensuring you get some return value, for example:

```
class ObjectA {
    var objectB: ObjectB? = null

    fun requireObjectB() = objectB ?: ObjectB().also { objectB = this }
}
```

This would already be an improvement to what you have. You could now do this:

```
objectA.requireObjectB().requireObjectC().requireObjectD().property = 1234
```

For better encapsulation, each object up the tree should have a public function for performing whatever you're doing so you aren't having to call deep into a chain. The calling class shouldn't have to have an intimate knowledge of the intricacies of a five-deep object tree. Any minor change to a class in the middle of the tree would blow up your project anywhere that something is trying to modify something deep in the tree. But if you have public functions on all these classes, you can ensure that changes are safe to make as long as the public functions still do what they're expected to.

Answer (score 0):

If the objects are required to exist anyway at this point, why not make them internally lazy?

```
class ObjectA {
    val objectB by lazy (::ObjectB)
}

class ObjectB {
    val objectC by lazy (::ObjectC)
}

class ObjectC {
    val objectD by lazy (::ObjectD)
}

class ObjectD {
    var property: Int? = null
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val objectA = ObjectA()
    objectA.objectB.objectC.objectD.property = 42
}
```

Much cleaner!